# VS 2022 Change font sizes on various UI elements - description of windows, panes and parts thereof

Tags: visual-studio, font-size

So I know that I can change the various UI elements on VS2022 by using Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors, which is great and I've managed to increase the font size of some options, but I'm stumped as to how to change the font size of the status bar at the bottom of an editing window. Man, it's so small and my eyes are dim...!!!

[image]

Anyone know what it is called?

Even more useful would be an image which describes/defines the names of all the UI elements on VS Studio so that I don't have to ask this question again. It surely must be somewhere, but I cannot find it!! :(

Thanks,
Gordon

Comment: VS assumes you've configured the machine to be a decent match with the monitor.  In Win10 use Settings > System > Display > "Scale and layout".  Looks like you need at least 150% there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I saw your question right now.
In VS 2022, try changing the value for *Text* in *[Watch, Locals, and Autos Tool Windows]*, that should help.

[image: Font setting]